# Typescript - function return type in interface

Tags: typescript

Trying to do this

```
interface SomeInterface {
    someProperty: string | () => JSX.Element
}
```

The property should be either a `string` or a `Function` that returns a `JSX.Element`. What's the proper syntax, if any?

Currently I'm doing the following as a better-than-nothing solution, but it's not what I want

```
interface SomeInterface {
    someProperty: string | Function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup this is correct with parenthesis :

```
interface SomeInterface {
    someProperty: string | (() => JSX.Element)
}


declare const s: SomeInterface

if (typeof s.someProperty === 'function') {
    s.someProperty() // JSX.Element
} else {
    s.someProperty // string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=44&pln=9&pc=31#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAsAFDJXIDOWEAClOgA7RgCeAXLWFKAHNkAH2QAKMQEpkAXgB8vfiAGSKAXwqbyAEwgIANnCgoE6EDTC0eGbHkixEELcBjjObdK5oA6Otias7ByyMjLIAOQwAK4gCGDAZuHSZJTUPn6MzGxQnFLIAPT5ioLqyBD6NCgp1LS+9AHZnAVFFkoC6lpAA)